# Possible breakages of Java code in future versions due to more zealous checks of statement reachability

Tags: java

It's well-known that Java will not compile code that contains sections that are not reachable.

It's also well known (the halting problem?) that determining reachability is impossible.

It's also possible to speculate that as Java compilers improve they will become better at determining reachability.

This creates a problem: it follows therefore that a new Java compiler might fail to compile Java code that previously worked. In other words, backward compatibility is not respected.

Am I correct here? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Dear downvoter, is there a way that I can improve this question?

Comment: I think non-reachable code produce just a warning when compiling Java code, so future Java compilers will do the same I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backwards compatibility is nice thing to have, but it's not a goal - most (if not every?) major Java releases have broken something.

That said, it seems very unlikely for [the part of the language specification that defines reachability](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) to change in the future. There's no clear benefit, and changing it can potentially break too many programs.

Comment: Oh I see. So there are sections in the JLS that define how a compiler must determine reachability?

Comment: of course - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21